# Is a custom TableCellEditor constructor only called once?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable. One column in the JTable is assigned an extended TableCellEditor that displays an extended JComboBox.

There is a fixed list of 100 String objects that populates the comboboxes.

The challenge:

- Design the JComboBoxes so that any selection is unique relative to other boxes? That is, if "A" is slected from the combobox in the first row, it is automatically removed from the list of each other combobox.
- When a new room is added to the table, the combobox it contains should auto-populate to the first available list item.

The problem:
My comboboxes work beautifully. I can select items at will. I even have made some progress in eliminating already used items from the lists. But I can't figure out how to correctly auto-populate.

I am very confused because it appears that my combobox constructor is only called once when the table is created, not once for each row.

Is this the case? Is the constructor for a TableCellEditor only called once ever? If so, how do I modify the behavior of each combobox as it come into existence?

Thanks for your help!

If you would like specific code, please let me know. I don't know if you want me to paste in the whole classes.

Comment: We don't want your entire code base.  If you could make a short example that illustrates the problem, with as few classes and methods as possible, that would be a big help.

Comment: `Is the constructor for a TableCellEditor only called once ever?` - the constructor for any object is only called once, when the object is created. `my combobox constructor is only called once when the table is created, not once for each row.` - the point of using editors and renderers is that the classes are shared by the table to minimize the number of objects created.

Answer (score 1):

> When a new room is added to the table, the combobox it contains should auto-populate to the first available list item.

When you add a new row of data to the TableModel you must add the values of all columns in the row. This should not be a function of the editor. The editor allows you to change values in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around my problem by creating an abstract superclass for my combobox that can be accessed from the tablemodel extension when it sets up its data.